# Xcode is showing some warnings

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I am new to iOS development. I want to know something:
My Xcode is showing some warnings in my code. These warnings belong to third party library. 
Does Apple store reject my app if it has few warnings in code??

Comment: You don't send code to Apple. They have no idea whether you have any warnings or not. Warnings should be fixed because many times they actually cause problems and you don't want to be in the habit of ignoring warnings. But most importantly, does your app work correctly?

Comment: Hey, thank you for your quick response. Actually, I am using Jsq Message View Controller and that library has been deprecated. It is working fine but still showing some warnings. What should I do??

Comment: Personally I would avoid anything that is deprecated. But the choice is yours. Apple doesn't care either way.

Comment: I am totally new to iOS development. Does not know much about iOS . I am following a tutorial where the instructor is using this library. If I use this deprecated library, will it cause any problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer makes a key assumption that you are using **Cocoapods** since you mention a third party library. If that is not the case, then ignore this.

As @rmaddy has pointed out, a deprecated library likely contains code that Apple is telling you "this works now, but it may stop working at some point in the future or behave in ways we cannot guarantee will be good". With that said, you are free to submit an app with all the warnings you can generate.

With that all said, you can make those warnings go away by adding the following line to your `Podfile`.

`inhibit_all_warnings!`

Add this line to the top of your Podfile, and then re-run `pod install`.

This tells Xcode to ignore *all* warnings generated by the libraries.

### Now for the disclaimer portion.

> You ignore these warnings at your own peril. Xcode is doing its best
>   to warn you of potentially bad things, but some times you just have to
>   use a library for some reason (I can think of some major projects from
>   well known tech companies) and that library is riddled with warnings.
>   Using the above statement can maintain sanity by dismissing warnings
>   that I frankly cannot do anything about.